# Simple Basic Calculator Multiple Additions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am making a very basic simple calculator for iPhone. I am using this sample code from GitHub and extending it.

https://github.com/teikenshi/xcode-calculator/tree/master/kadai06

Here's the problem I have. If I wanted to add these numbers together

2,5,6,8

With the current code I have to push the buttons in this order

```
2 + 5 =

+ 6 =

+ 8 =
```

Meaning I have to push the equal button every time I add two numbers

What I would like to do is how normal people add numbers i.e. they will push the number button and click on the plus button in this order

```
2 + 5 + 6 + 8 (calculator keeps adding the numbers up and shows the addition results).
```

Now I admit this isn't the most elegant code nor the best calculator code, but if someone can help me either fix this code or point me to a better sample calculator code then I am all open.

```
- (IBAction)plus:(id)sender
{
//what code logic should go in here. 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I understand neither the question nor your code.

Comment: @MartinR I have re-worded my question a bit, does that help?

Comment: So you update the sum only when = is pressed. How about updating it whenever a + is pressed ?

Comment: @SamBudda you need some algorithm here. ok, you can store result of sum of two numbers in variable. 3+5+7 should work like (3+5) + 7 => 8 + 7. Put 3 into firstVar and 5 into secondVar. next, do this: firstVar+=secondVar, secondVar = 7. And so on. While secondVar = -1 or string of your expression is over.

Comment: Do as @KhanhNguyen suggested or implement it to use reverse polish notation.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen trust me I tried that it doesn't work. You can try downloading that project and see

Comment: I am just about ready to give up on this sample code. It's just pure confusion and only make sense to the guy who wrote it. Can anyone point me to a sample but robust calculator code that uses NSDecimalNumber and NSNumberFormatter?

Comment: I like @KhanhNguyen's suggestion. When the user presses an operation key, execute the previous operation. Operation keys include '='.

Comment: @nielsbot I tried that, it doesn't work for this code.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to suggest simpler way..
This is rough idea how it can be carried out for sum '+'

*1.* Just display what user types in textfield and operation like '+' by appending strings to display label.

*2.* When user hits '=' equal just read label back and perform operation based on what label is set.

*3.* Perform calculation like this

```
NSArray *subStrings = [displayLabel componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];

double answer = 0;

for(NSString *value in subStrings)
{
   answer = answer + [value doubleValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:
1. The user pressed on the plus button, the button will be bordered or whatever sign you wanna give to the button.
2. if the plus button is pressed, you wait to the numbers (0 - 9) once the user press it you release the plus button and calculate the results. and show it to the user.

That's way you just calculate the results even if the user isn't pressed the equal button.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the running result of the calculator in a variable and handle it for different operations. Maybe for the plus try something like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *result;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *calculatorDisplay;

- (IBAction)plus:(id)sender
  {
    if (!self.result) {
         self.result = self.calculatorDisplay.text;
    } else {
         // Otherwise we have to add the previous result to the current display
         double toAdd = [self.calculatorDisplay.text doubleValue];
         double current = [self.result doubleValue];
         double result = current + toAdd;
         self.result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
    }
  }
```

Then maybe in a clear IBAction you reset self.result back to nil;